# Emma(Emmarun) is not working with java 8 .main class not found error

Tags: java, emma, emmarun

I am using Emmarun(java  emmarun -cp . myApp.jar) to generate code coverage report for my project but its not working with java8. getting below error:

EMMA: no metadata collected at runtime [no reports generated]
[EMMA v2.1, build 5214 (stable)]
emmarun: [MAIN_CLASS_NOT_FOUND] application class [TestCoverageExampleApplication.jar] could not be loaded

> I tried (java -XX:-UseSplitVerifier emmarun -cp . myApp) solution but its also not working.